# Nested 'justify-content: space-around' not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 parent containers with 2 child containers in them. (Altogether there are 4 containers.) The wrapper that everything is wrapped in, and the wrapper that the 2 parent containers are in, are set to the following css style:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
```

**Problem**
The wrapper that the 2 parent containers are in, doesn't seem to register the `justify-content: space-around;`

**Trying to Accomplish**
I want all containers to have `justify-content: space-around;`. In addition to that, I want the 2 child containers to have `justify-content: space-around;`. Something like this:

[image]

I still want the 'less space' to adjust as the page size adjusts. So I therefore can't just add a margin to it.

#### JSFiddle

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.outerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.heading {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="outerWrapper">
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: orange;">
      <li class="heading">FIRST</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <li class="heading">Second</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="outerWrapper">
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: pink;">
      <li class="heading">Third</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: burlywood;">
      <li class="heading">Fourth</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flex items in the main container use content width by default. This means the *children of the items* (First, Second, etc.) are packed together and `justify-content:space-around` has no space to work.

*main container (`#container`): red border // flex items (`.outerWrapper`): black border*

[image]

Add `flex: 1` to `.outerWrapper`:

[image]

Now both items occupy the full available width of `#container`, and `justify-content: space-around` has space to work.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.outerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  flex: 1;
}
.heading {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="outerWrapper">
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: orange;">
      <li class="heading">FIRST</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <li class="heading">Second</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="outerWrapper">
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: pink;">
      <li class="heading">Third</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: burlywood;">
      <li class="heading">Fourth</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a54upjnf/4/)

To create additional space between the first two and last two items (like the image in the question), one method introduces a third flex item between them.

[image]

You can then control the width of each item with the `flex` property.

```
.outerWrapper:nth-child(1) { flex: 2; }
.outerWrapper:nth-child(2) { flex: 1; }
.outerWrapper:nth-child(3) { flex: 2; }
```

You'll need to remove this spacer item when the boxes begin to wrap on smaller screens. Here's one way to do that:

```
@media ( max-width: 450px ) {
  .outerWrapper:nth-child(2) { display: none; }  
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a54upjnf/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a min width for the child element(`.outerWrapper` ) and also try to add a margin to the `ul` to work in responsive.

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.outerWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
      min-width:35%;
}
.outerWrapper ul:first-child {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.heading {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="outerWrapper">
        <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: orange;">
            <li class="heading">FIRST</li>
            <li class="list">Item #01</li>
            <li class="list">Item #02</li>
            <li class="list">Item #03</li>
            <li class="list">Item #04</li>
            <li class="list">Item #05</li>
            <li class="list">Item #06</li>
            <li class="list">Item #07</li>
            <li class="list">Item #08</li>
            <li class="list">Item #09</li>
            <li class="list">Item #10</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: lightblue;">
            <li class="heading">Second</li>
            <li class="list">Item #01</li>
            <li class="list">Item #02</li>
            <li class="list">Item #03</li>
            <li class="list">Item #04</li>
            <li class="list">Item #05</li>
            <li class="list">Item #06</li>
            <li class="list">Item #07</li>
            <li class="list">Item #08</li>
            <li class="list">Item #09</li>
            <li class="list">Item #10</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="outerWrapper">
        <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: pink;">
            <li class="heading">Third</li>
            <li class="list">Item #01</li>
            <li class="list">Item #02</li>
            <li class="list">Item #03</li>
            <li class="list">Item #04</li>
            <li class="list">Item #05</li>
            <li class="list">Item #06</li>
            <li class="list">Item #07</li>
            <li class="list">Item #08</li>
            <li class="list">Item #09</li>
            <li class="list">Item #10</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: burlywood;">
            <li class="heading">Fourth</li>
            <li class="list">Item #01</li>
            <li class="list">Item #02</li>
            <li class="list">Item #03</li>
            <li class="list">Item #04</li>
            <li class="list">Item #05</li>
            <li class="list">Item #06</li>
            <li class="list">Item #07</li>
            <li class="list">Item #08</li>
            <li class="list">Item #09</li>
            <li class="list">Item #10</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin-right` style to `ul:first-child`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.outerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.outerWrapper ul:first-child {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.heading {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="outerWrapper">
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: orange;">
      <li class="heading">FIRST</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: lightblue;">
      <li class="heading">Second</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="outerWrapper">
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: pink;">
      <li class="heading">Third</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="wrapper" style="background-color: burlywood;">
      <li class="heading">Fourth</li>
      <li class="list">Item #01</li>
      <li class="list">Item #02</li>
      <li class="list">Item #03</li>
      <li class="list">Item #04</li>
      <li class="list">Item #05</li>
      <li class="list">Item #06</li>
      <li class="list">Item #07</li>
      <li class="list">Item #08</li>
      <li class="list">Item #09</li>
      <li class="list">Item #10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Um.. Thanks, but I think I said in the question "I still want the 'less space' to adjust as the page size adjusts. So I therefore can't just add a margin to it."